# (Silverlight newbie) Trying to add custom object as a Child of a WrapPanel (on code behind)

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a WrapPanel where I add a bunch of rectangle controls I got everything working,
but now I have decided that it would be better to create a class for them and instead of creating rectangles all over the place I'll just instantiate new objects.

I did it but the problem is that now I get an error when I try to add my object as a Child to the WrapPanel or anywhere for that matter.

> Error: The best overloaded method
>   match for
>   'System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection.Add(System.Windows.UIElement)'
>   has some invalid arguments

I tried extending my class with the UIElement class

```
 public class myColor : UIElement {...}
```

this didn't work either as I'm missing the constructors for the UIElement class
Error:

> The type 'System.Windows.UIElement' has no constructors defined

I'm still learning Silverlight and c#, any help would be appreciated it,
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight does not allow you to inherit `UIElement` as it is possible in WPF.  You can inherit from `FrameworkElement` or take it one step further and inherit from `Control`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the `UIElement` class can be extended.  You could use extension methods or you could try inheriting from a `FrameworkElement`.